# Can I apply for USA tourist visa when my passport is expiring in 6 months time?

Tags: visas, usa

Can I apply for US  tourist visa when my Passport is expiring in 6 months time ?

Answer (score 2):

See [9 FAM 403.9-3(B)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B) for passport validity requirements for issuing a nonimmigrant visa.

For passports from countries in the "6-month club", it says that a visa can be issued at any time until the expiration date, though it does mention that if it's too close to expiration it "might not be practical" (9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(2)(b)):

> As passports issued by the countries listed in paragraph f below meet
>   the requirements of INA 212(a)(7)(B)(i)(I) until the date shown for
>   expiration, the consular officer could issue a visa at any time prior
>   to that date.  However, such action might not be practical when only a
>   very narrow margin of time remains.

For passports from countries not in the "6-month club", 9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(1) says that a visa should only be issued when the passport is valid for 6 months beyond the initial period of stay:

> A nonimmigrant visa is only to be issued in passports that are valid
>   for at least six months beyond the initial period of contemplated stay
>   in the United States, except in the following circumstances:

But 9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(3) says that this is not absolutely required, and that a visa can still be issued when the passport is valid for more than 6 months but does not cover the period of stay, if it's not feasible to renew the passport beforehand:

> If an applicant presents a passport valid for more than six months but
>   not sufficient to permit admission for the entire period of stay
>   contemplated, the consular officer should urge the applicant to have
>   the passport extended, renewed, or replaced before visa issuance.  In
>   the event that this is not feasible until after the alien’s arrival in
>   the United States, the officer may issue the visa.  The officer should
>   then advise the applicant that the initial period of stay will be
>   limited because of the limited validity of the passport.  The consular
>   officer should also explain the procedures for seeking an extension of
>   stay from the Department of Homeland Security (DHS).  Except for
>   aliens covered by the provisions of 9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(2) above, the
>   passport must be valid for more than six months, since an alien
>   presenting a passport valid for six months or less would be
>   inadmissible at a port of entry (POE).

Answer (score 1):

There is a "six-month club" https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update
If your country is on the list, your passport only need to valid for the stay, otherwise it needs to be valid 6 months after your leave.

Comment: The US also accepts valid visas in expired passports, so it's not clear that the minimum validity required for a visit has any bearing on the minimum validity for an application.